# What was the large pack of Darkhounds searching for?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

While searching for the Shaido in WoT Book 10 "Crossroads of Twilight", Perrin's group found that

> a huge pack of Darkhounds - 50 or so instead of the usual 10 - had made a complete circle around their camp during the night and then continued on south.

Obviously the pack wasn't after Perrin, since they left. However, a pack that huge - a size not seen again until the Last Battle - must have been after something fairly important. However, I don't recall the pack being brought up again at any time afterwards.

**What prey was the pack of Darkhounds searching for?**

Comment: I don't think we ever find out for sure, but the fact that there's so many of them (so it must be a powerful target) and they seem like they've been hunting for a while (and aren't even willing to detract from their hunt for such a juicy target as Perrin's camp) suggests to me that it's likely a target who can move around very quickly, so likely either Travelling or using the Ways. My guess is that they're after either Rand or Padan Fain.

Comment: Also I think somewhere in the books it is mentioned that packs can't join, they would attack each other. I think Moiraine says it at some point in the 3rd book?

Comment: @Amarth - yes, and the Aes Sedai investigating the tracks above commented on it as well. She said something like it would take the Dark One himself to command a hunt of that magnitude... so, Ishmael, maybe?

Comment: Been quite a while since I read it. Though around the same time in Crossroads, the [wiki](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Crossroads_of_Twilight/Chapter_8) says that the following happened: "Suddenly colors burst into Perrin's mind and he sees an image of Rand and Nynaeve. Grady and the Wise Ones are concerned because they can sense vast amounts of the One Power being channelled."  I don't know what this could be, but it could be related? Was this around the time they used the two giant sa'angreal to do [spoiler alert]? The event stirred up all manner things and Ishamael would try to stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the last battle a huge pack attacks, as huge packs are very rare I have made the assumption that they are the same pack. As Rand was fighting at the Bore for a long time he had stopped moving allowing them to find him. So at long last they found him at the Bore but were prevented from getting to him by Perrin, the Aiel, the remaining soldiers and the Heroes of the Horn, both human and wolves.